# Python modeling language for ordinary differential equations?

Tags: python, scipy

I am working on ordinary differential equations that I want to solve using numerical methods in Python. Some of these ODEs are chemical equations, e.g. A + B > C with stoichiometry coefficient sigma. This leads to the differential equation du/dt = sigma * a * b.
To do this, the classical method is to use e.g. a Runge-Kutta solver, such as the one in Scipy's [integrate.ode](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy//reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html).

Instead, I would like to use a modeling language similar to [cvxpy](https://www.cvxpy.org/) is for convex optimization. This method would allow to formally define the ODE and automatically solve the equation. It would be similar, in Python, to what is done in OpenModelica.

Is there such a tool?

Comment: Not an answer but a comment: if you can't find what you need in Python, Julia has you covered with Catalyst.jl: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVfxT09AtWQ

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. I must mention that I am not exclusively interested in chemical reactions. For example, I am also interested in differential equations such as dT/dt = -phi - alpha * T * c and dc / dt = - beta * T * c where phi, alpha and beta are constants.

Comment: Cool! Give DifferentialEquations.j a try then :) I myself have been moving projects from C++ to Julia because of the ease to work with Python-style C-efficient code :)